# How to get wanted nodes from Stanford Parser NLP?

Tags: parsing, nodes, stanford-nlp

My main problem is that I don't know how to extract nodes from GrammaticalStructure.
I am using englishPCFG.ser in java netbeans.
My target is to know the quality of the screen like:

*The screen of iphone 4 is great.*

I want to extract screen and great.
How can I extract the NN (screen) and VP (great) ?

the code that I wrote is:

```
LexicalizedParser lp = new LexicalizedParser("C:\\englishPCFG.ser");
lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories"});

String sent ="the screen is very good.";
Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent));
parse.pennPrint();
System.out.println();

TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
```

Answer (score 2):

The collection `tdl` is a list of typed dependencies.  For this sentence, it contains:

```
det(screen-2, the-1)
nsubj(great-7, screen-2)
amod(4-5, iphone-4)
prep_of(screen-2, 4-5)
cop(great-7, is-6)
```

(as you can see by trying it out [online](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)).

So, the dependency you want, `nsubj(great-7, screen-2)` is right there in that list.  `nsubj` means that "screen" is the subject of "great".

The collection of dependencies is just a Collection (List).  For doing more sophisticated further processing, people commonly want to make the dependencies into a graph structure that can be variously searched and traversed.  There are various ways of doing that.  We often use the (jgrapht)[http://www.jgrapht.org/] library.  But that's then code you are writing yourself.

Comment: is there a way for me to search for a relation in a sentence?  In this case can I search for e.g., amod?  Or do I need to get the relns and then check if there is amod?